# Check floor congruence in 2D array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on a maze generation algorithm. My algorithm selects from predefined tiles and creates a maze. Here is an example produced by my code. '**' is a wall and '__' is empty floor space.

```
** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** ** __ ** ** ** ** 
** ** __ __ __ __ __ ** ** ** ** 
** ** __ __ __ __ __ ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** __ ** ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** __ ** ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ ** ** __ ** ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** ** ** __ __ __ ** 
** __ ** __ ** ** ** __ __ ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** ** ** __ ** ** ** 
** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **
```

I need to create a function that will test to see if all floor space is connected. i.e. make sure that all '__' spaces can be reached from every other '__' space. That would mean the above maze is illegal but the below is acceptable.

```
** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** 
** ** __ ** __ __ __ __ __ __ ** 
** __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ ** 
** ** __ ** __ __ ** ** __ ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** ** ** __ __ __ ** 
** __ __ ** ** ** ** __ __ __ ** 
** __ __ __ ** ** ** __ __ __ ** 
** ** ** __ ** ** ** ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ __ __ __ __ ** ** ** ** 
** __ __ __ ** ** ** ** ** ** ** 
** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **
```

I'm not sure how to best approach this problem. I think I should use a BFS search, but I'm not 100% sure. All suggestions welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) the floors from some starting floor. You can do this either by having another 2D array just for this. You can use BFS(queue-based) or DFS(stack-based). The point is just to make an exhaustive search.

Run through the maze again. If you find any floor that hasn't been filled in the above step, we know it's not connected to the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I have waaaaaaaaaay too much spare time, the code works as intended but some of the methods could probably be done a little better.

**Main**

```
package maze;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Create a new maze and populate it.
        Maze maze = new Maze(11, 11);
        maze.populate();

        //Get the total number of floor tiles in the entire maze.
        int totalFloor = maze.getTotalFloorCount();

        //Get the total number of floor tiles in a section.
        int sectionFloor = maze.getSectionFloorCount(maze.x, maze.y);

        //If the section has an equal amount of floor tiles with the entire maze, then the maze is connected.
        System.out.println("Section/Total: " + sectionFloor + "/" + totalFloor);
        if (sectionFloor == totalFloor)
        {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS! Maze is valid!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL! Maze is not valid!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Tile**

```
package maze;

public class Tile
{
    public static final String FLOOR = "__";
    public static final String WALL = "**";

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Tile(int x, int y)
    {
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    /** ---------------------------------------- **/
    /** --- GETTERS & SETTERS                --- **/
    /** ---------------------------------------- **/

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**Maze**

```
package maze;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Maze
{
    //Maze dimensions.
    private int mazeDimX = 11;
    private int mazeDimY = 11;
    private String[][] array;

    //Last found floor tile coordinates.
    public int x = -1;
    public int y = -1;

    public Maze(int mazeDimX, int mazeDimY)
    {
        this.mazeDimX = mazeDimX;
        this.mazeDimY = mazeDimY;
        array = new String[mazeDimX][mazeDimY];
    }

    /** ---------------------------------------- **/
    /** --- METHODS                          --- **/
    /** ---------------------------------------- **/

    public void populate()
    {
        //Insert code to populate maze here.
    }

    public int getTotalFloorCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<mazeDimX; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<mazeDimY; j++)
            {
                if (array[i][j].equals(Tile.FLOOR))
                {
                    //Increase the total count of floor tiles.
                    count++;

                    //Stores the last found floor tile.
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int getSectionFloorCount(int x, int y)
    {
        int tileCount = 0;

        List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        List<Tile> removedTiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        if (x != -1 && y != -1)
        {
            tiles.add(new Tile(x, y));
        }

        while (!tiles.isEmpty())
        {
            //Increase current tile count.
            tileCount++;

            //Get next tile.
            Tile tile = tiles.get(0);

            //Get x and y of tile.
            int tileX = tile.getX();
            int tileY = tile.getY();

            //Get up, down, left and right tiles.
            Tile up =       getAdjacentTile(tileX, tileY - 1);
            Tile down =     getAdjacentTile(tileX, tileY + 1);
            Tile left =     getAdjacentTile(tileX - 1, tileY);
            Tile right =    getAdjacentTile(tileX + 1, tileY);

            //Add tile if required.
            addTile(tiles, removedTiles, up);
            addTile(tiles, removedTiles, down);
            addTile(tiles, removedTiles, left);
            addTile(tiles, removedTiles, right);

            //Move the tile from the checked list to the removed list.
            tiles.remove(tile);
            removedTiles.add(tile);
        }
        return tileCount;
    }

    private Tile getAdjacentTile(int x, int y)
    {
        //Check if the tile is in bounds.
        if (x >= 0 && x < mazeDimX && y >= 0 && y < mazeDimY)
        {
            //Check if the tile is a floor.
            if (array[x][y].equals(Tile.FLOOR))
            {
                return new Tile(x, y);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void addTile(List<Tile> tiles, List<Tile> removedTiles, Tile tile)
    {
        boolean isRemoved = false;
        if (tile != null)
        {
            //Check if the tile has already been removed.
            for (int i=0; i<removedTiles.size(); i++)
            {
                Tile removed = removedTiles.get(i);
                if (tile.getX() == removed.getX() && tile.getY() == removed.getY())
                {
                    isRemoved = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isRemoved)
            {
                boolean isInList = false;
                //Check if the tile already is in the list to be checked.
                for (int i=0; i<tiles.size(); i++)
                {
                    Tile item = tiles.get(i);
                    if (tile.getX() == item.getX() && tile.getY() == item.getY())
                    {
                        isInList = true;
                    }
                }
                //Add the tile if it hasn't been checked or removed already.
                if (!isInList)
                {
                    tiles.add(tile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple A* search would work well for that purpose, although depending on the size of your maze it could be a tad slow. In pseudo-code:

```
for(t=0; t<arrayOfAllTiles.length; t++) {
    for(i=t; i<arrayOfAllTiles.length; i++) {
        if(doAStarTest(i, t) == false) {
            //oh no, not congruent
        }
    }
}
```

Red Blob Games has some spectacular tutorials, including one on A*: http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html